# Include a particular line to all modules in VBA in a faster and more efficient way?

Tags: excel, vba

Lets say i have this particular code:

```
Dim siteCount As long
```

that i have forgotten to include in all my modules and the thing is i have around 100+ modules to include this line.

Therefore, it would be a tedious process to just copy and paste this line into all my modules. Hence, is there a faster way such that i can add this line of code to all my modules in my workbook in VBA? (So far i have only used find and replace all to some of my existing codes but it does not help in the case when i need to add new code like `Dim siteCount As long`)

Comment: @BigBen I have edited but why long?

Comment: My guess is you'll spend more time writing a method to do this than if you just figure out the find and replace patterns and do it manually. This situation comes up so rarely that it's not worth writing your own function to do it. Look at the RubberDuck VBA add-in, which may have some capability to help though.